# Retrieving custom field value with get_post?

Tags: custom-field, get-post

There's no mention of custom fields values in [Get_post's codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post). Is it impossible to use get_post to get a custom field value of some post, and if so, is it necessary to perform a whole loop just for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the [custom field functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) accept the post id as a parameter. You can use all those functions directly without the need to actually retrieve the post itself.

Comment: Also, when fetching with get_posts, WP_Query, etc, all meta fields and taxonomies are usually prefetched and cached, so each call to get_post_meta will be server from cache rather than hitting the db.